Irreducible faithful representations within faithful group actions
Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose $G$ acts faithfully on a set $I$. This gives rise to a representation
$$
\rho : G \to \operatorname{Sym}(I) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{R} (\mathbb{R}^I).
$$
Given an irreducible faithful representation $\theta : G \to \operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(V)$, does $\theta$ necessarily appear as a subrepresentation of $\rho$? If not, what is a counterexample?
Here is an example to illustrate the hypotheses. Let $G = S_3$. The nontrivial irreducible representations of $S_3$ are the sign representation and the standard representation. Consider the standard action of $S_3$ on the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. This is a faithful action, and its associated representation decomposes as the direct sum of the standard representation and a one-dimensional trivial representation. Note the standard representation is faithful and appears in this decomposition, while the sign representation is not faithful and does not appear.

Suppose $G$ has two faithful irreps: $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, then $\theta_2$ does not appear in $\theta_1$ and $\theta_1$ does not appear in $\theta_2$.

@khashayar But neither $\theta_1$ nor $\theta_2$ arise from a group action (any such rep must contain a trivial component, thus is not a nontrivial irrep). Note that $\rho$ must arise from a group action.

Let $G=S_4$. $G$ acts on $I=\{1,2,3,4\}$ faithfully by permuting its elements. This action induces a four-dimensional rep $\rho$. We can see $\rho=triv\oplus std$, and it does not contain the other faithful irrep which is the tensor product of sign irrep and standard irrep. Here you can find irreps of $S_4$: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S4
